# C language, if statement confusion

Tags: c, if-statement

UPDATE: The code now runs perfect

close UPDATE.

> You'll need to account for two different cases: buying an even number of milk cartons and buying an odd number of milk cartons.  How can you determine if a number is even or odd?

This is what I have written so far and I would like some guidance please. I hope I'm making sense.

```
    if (milk_boxes % 2 == 0)


    total = milk_boxes * milk_price / 2;
    else


    total = (milk_boxes - 1) * milk_price / 2 + milk_price;
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Is your code working as intended?  If not, could you tell us what the result is?

Comment: what are you confused about?

Comment: The only way you get the deal is if you buy in pairs. If a carton of OJ is $4, and you buy one, you pay $4 with true BOGO. If you buy two, you pay $4. If you buy three, you pay $8. If you buy four, you pay $8. Forget the code for a moment, can you figure out the algorithm on paper?

Comment: Read [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and more [about the C programming language](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c), perhaps the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), see also http://norvig.com/21-days.html for an insight

Comment: If your C compiler is [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), compile with all warnings and debug info, so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`; even if your C compiler is something else, read its documentation.

Comment: thank you guys, so I was confused about a very simple thing... thanks @yano for that I think I'm a little closer this time, I need to fix he very last part to get it correct. -  printf("The total cost is $%1f\n", (OJ_containers*OJ_price)/2)+OJ_price;  -

Comment: You cannon use any input-function correctly unless you ***Check The Return***. E.g.  `if (scanf("%lf", &OJ_price) != 1) { fputs ("error: invalid double value.\n", stderr); return 1; }` and the same for `OJ_containers` with the error message `"error: invalid integer value.\n"` ... Develop good habits early. Replace `system("pause");` with `for (int c = getchar(); c != EOF; c = getchar()) {} getchar();` (which will remove all characters in `stdin` and then wait for the next keypress -- holding the terminal for your IDE open in a standards compliant way)

Comment: try to do this for odd values : to achieve pairing just do this : printf ("The total cost is $ %1f",(OJ_containers*OJ_price) - OJ_price);

Comment: @DanielWalker The code is not doing the right math for the odd number section. I was thinking something like this.. printf ("The total cost is $ %.2f\n",((OJ_containers-1)*OJ_price)+OJ_price); I'm not getting the correct answer and I think I'm not using the correct order of operations maybe?

Comment: All you're missing is a `/2` in your "odd" expression. `n` containers at `p` price: `n * p / 2` for even and `(n - 1) * p / 2 + p` for odd. But since integer division truncates, you can just use `n * p / 2 + p` for odd if you want.

Comment: Glad you got it working! In the future though, please remember that SO is a question and answer site, whose purpose is to catalog knowledge for future users. Only edit your question to add details or clarity. Your question is not supposed to be a live update of your current code or progress. Your "question" as it stands now is in shambles, a shell of its former self. If I happened across this now, I would have no idea what the problem statement was or what was solved. Furthermore, large deviations from the original question can obsolete comments/answers, further confusing future readers.

Comment: @yano I will keep this in mind, thanks a lot for the help and clarifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not dividing by 2 for the BOGO offer in your "odd" case. Example follows - I separated the `printf` out to clarify things a bit.

```
double total;

if (OJ_containers % 2 == 0)
    // even means simply divide full price by two
    total = OJ_containers * OJ_price / 2;
else
    // odd means half price for the pairs, plus one more bottle at full price
    total = (OJ_containers - 1) * OJ_price / 2 + OJ_price;

printf("The total cost is %f\n", total);
```

Comment: Thank you! that's what I was missing, making a 3rd variable (total)  and then go from there with the math. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I can see one issue in your code. You are calculating and displaying the price if the containers which are in odd numbers. But I think you forget to calculate the price of the containers if they are even in numbers, You are just printing value of the variable OJ_containers. You have to calculate and display it also.

As you are looking for the guidelines, I would suggest you should follow the Microsoft's coding guidelines :

[The Microsoft's coding guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions)

I know it is for c# but you can still use those guidelines for other programming languages also. Many things are in common to other programming languages. like concept of variables, functions- in c# they call it as method. Hope you like it. as you progress you will get to know there are many programming approaches but don't confuse, just follow the standard once and I would like you to do this from the beginning, it will help you to become a good programmer.

Try this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    double OJ_price;
    int OJ_containers;

    printf("What is the cost of one container of OJ in dollars?\n");
    scanf("%lf", &OJ_price);

    printf("How many containers are you buying?\n");
    scanf("%d", &OJ_containers);

    if(OJ_containers % 2 == 0)
        printf("The total cost is %1f\n", (OJ_containers*OJ_price)/2);
    else
        printf("The total cost is $ %.2f\n",                      
((OJ_containers/2)*OJ_price)+OJ_price);

return 0;

}
```

Comment: I would not give this advice in this case: different language, too advanced topics, and personally I don't like m$ ideas.

Comment: Hey! thanks for your help, I have edited the code and I think I'm a little closer to get it correct this time. I'm still getting the wrong amount when I input an odd number.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica says Reinstate Monica I just telling him to follow the naming convention topic of the Microsoft coding guidelines section. I got Your concern :), That it contains advanced topics but to start good coding practice I suggest him to go through the naming convensions topics only. :)

Comment: try to do this for odd values : to achieve pairing just do this :
printf ("The total cost is $ %1f",(OJ_containers*OJ_price) - OJ_price);

Comment: thx, I did that and I'm not getting the correct answer. I was thinking something like this.. printf ("The total cost is $ %.2f\n",((OJ_containers-1)*OJ_price)+OJ_price);  I'm not getting the correct answer and I think I'm not using the correct  order of operations maybe?

Comment: let me explain it to you, if we buy 3 containers and we are setting one container price =4$  then our desired output should be 8$ okay? then if we calculate 4*4*4=12
and if we consider buy one get one free offer then 4*4*4-4=8 that is, (no. of container * price of one container)-price of one container

Comment: This program is missing the same `/2` that OP's is.

Comment: sorry, you are right the ((OJ_containers/2)*OJ_price)+OJ_price); would give you the price of odd containers, I've Edited My answer